# Showing local files on a php server with React

Tags: php, raspberry-pi

Say I have a Raspberry pi running Linux. I want to make it into a php server with endpoints that a React frontend can connect to, so I can browse for local media files on the server and play them via a web browser. I have zero experience with php, so I wonder if that's even possible? Would I have to upload the files whenever I wanted to play one? Or is it possible to access them directly and just host the media player in my React app?

Everything would be running on local network only, so security shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: You can install an apache or nginx server, then install php-fpm, and then put .php files in root folder of the server and connect to it. It is as easy as it gets.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/apache.md this documentation is perfect, i personally have been using raspi for almost all of my tasks!

Comment: By "_local media files_" you mean files on the Raspberry? Or on your client?

Comment: @JackSparrow So how would the files be accessed then? Something like {IPaddress}/folder/mediafile.mp4? Would it be possible to get the folder tree structure to make it easier to browse files?

Comment: @kerbholz The media files would be on the Raspberry, and I would want to access them from any other device connected to that network

Comment: @Telanore yes, .php files will serve anything you would serve with .html for example. Lets say you want to make folder called YourseverIP/media, go to root folder, make media/ and put index.php in media folder, so you can either browse by YourServerIP/media directly or YourServerIP/media/index.php. Just dont forget to add index.php to your index files in your server config so your server looks for index.php first in a folder!